# Compiling OpenCL on Ubuntu

Tags: opencl, ati

My programming experience is about 1 year of C/C++ experience from high school, but I did my research and wrote a simple program with OpenCL a few months ago. I was able to compile and run this on an Apple computer relatively easily with g++ and the --framework option. Now I'm on my Ubuntu machine and I have no idea how to compile it. The correct drivers have been downloaded along with ATI's Stream SDK (I have an ATI Radeon HD5870). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: NVIDIA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542808/what-is-needed-to-compile-opencl-on-ubuntu-and-by-extension-opencl-period/33483311#33483311

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
locate libOpenCL.so
```

If it is in one of the standard directories (most likely /usr/lib, or /usr/local/lib) you need to replace "--framework OpenCL" with "-lOpenCL". If g++ cannot find the lib you can tell g++ to look in a specific directory by adding "-L/path/to/library".

I wish I had my Linux to be more helpful... It is probably best if you redownload the ati-stream-sdk, after extracting it, open the Terminal and "cd /path/to/extracted/files"; in that directory execute `make && sudo make install`

- `make` you probably know this from windows, this compiles, whatever needs to be compiled
- `&&` chains commands together, the following commands will only be executed if the first command succeeded
- `sudo make install` this will put the files in the expected places (sudo executes a command with superuser priviledges, you will have to enter your password)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried this, but then I get the error "fatal error: CL/opencl.h: No such file or directory" (one of the things that I #included in my program).

Comment: maybe you need to tell g++ about the location of the "CL/" directory (you do this with a "dash capital i"): g++ -L/path/to/library -I/path/to/CL main.cpp -lOpenCL

Comment: Now I'm getting: 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

Maybe I should be asking whether I am supposed to have moved around files from the SDK folder into different parts of my filesystem. I apologize, I am new to Linux (just recently trying to switch from Windows).

Comment: And she compiles and runs! Unfortunately, I wrote this when OpenCL was still in the beta...so apparently some code changes are needed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, and in case anyone is in a similar position, the final line to compile was: "g++ -lOpenCL -L/stream-sdk-2.2/lib/x86_64/ -I/stream-sdk-2.2/include/ [file_name].c"

Comment: I had to run `g++ -L/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/ -I/opt/AMDAPP/include [filename.cpp] -lOpenCL`

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the dynamic libraries from the dynamic linker configuration.

Search for where the libraries are. Most likely /usr/lib, or /usr/local/lib.

Make sure the path location is also configured at one of these places:

- LD_LIBRARY_PATH - you can set it in you environment shell, like .bashrc
- /etc/ld.so.conf - you will need to call ldconfig to update the cache and it requires root access to change the file.

Answer (score 0):

## Reason

Aside from @bjoernz, my system can't find the `libOpenCL.so` file

It's because the correct file directory is missing

After searchig over the internet, I found out that `libOpenCL.so` file can provided by `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` package

## Solution

You just need to install the package mentioned above by typing into cmd

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

Therefore, `libOpenCL.so` can be found under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder

## My System Information

- **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- **GPU**: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660
- **GPU Driver**: nvidia-375
- **OpenCL**: 1.2

### Reference:

[1] [How to install libOpenCL.so on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796770/how-to-install-libopencl-so-on-ubuntu/796773#796773)

[2] [How to set up OpenCL in Linux](https://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo#Installing_the_Nvidia_ICD)