# OpenCL compile on linux

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I'm a newbie in OpenCL.

From yesterday, I'm trying to use OpenCL for parallel programming instead of CUDA which is more familiar for me and experienced before.

Now I have NVIDIA GTX 580 GPU, Ubuntu Linux 12.04 OS and CUDA SDK 4.1 (already installed before because of CUDA programming).

In CUDA SDK folder, Some OpenCL header file and library are already included.

So I just downloaded OpenCL examples from NVIDIA's Developer zone.
(Here is the link! https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl)

And I'm tried to compile some example by myself, but I couldn't.

I make Makefile by using -I I added path of header file, but I don't know how to added library path and what is the name of OpenCL library.

I searched on Google but someone said file named libOpenCL.so, but I only have OpenCL.lib.

Is Someone can help me?

Comment: .lib is for windows static lib, did you download the right package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is needed to compile opencl on ubuntu? (and by extension, opencl period)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542808/what-is-needed-to-compile-opencl-on-ubuntu-and-by-extension-opencl-period)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Install

The following steps have been tested on Ubuntu 12.04.

1. Download the [Intel SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl) for Linux.
2. Extract the RPM:

   ```
   $ tar zxvf intel_sdk_for_ocl_applications_2012_x64.tgz
   ```
3. Convert to .deb and install:

   ```
   $ fakeroot alien --to-deb intel_ocl_sdk_2012_x64.rpm
   $ sudo dpkg -i intel-ocl-sdk_2.0-31361_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Ensure that libOpenCL.so has been installed to /usr/lib/.

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so
   $ sudo ldconfig
   ```

## Compile

Simply link to the OpenCL library during compilation:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -lOpenCL
$ ./a.out
```

Comment: Don't forget the opencl headers if necessary 
https://askubuntu.com/a/693043/655911