# opencl Compilation errors

Tags: compiler-errors, opencl

I am new to OpenCL, I installed the intel sdk for opencl according to the answer on this thread:
[OpenCL compile on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977216/opencl-compile-on-linux)
But my opencl code won't compile. I am having an error message "CL/cl.hpp:No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CL/cl.hpp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.hpp) is a header file from [Khronos](https://www.khronos.org) group (the body behind the OpenCL standard) implementing [C++ Bindings Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.2.pdf). As far as I know, OpenCL providers are not required to provide the file with their packages, so you can download it from the Khronos [registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl).