# NVIDIA OpenCL sample compile

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I'm a newbie in OpenCL.

Now I'm trying to compile one of the NVIDIA OPENCL SDK CODE SAMPLES named "OpenCL Bandwidth Test" linked here (https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl).

In this sample, a file named "oclBandwidthTest.cpp" is included.

And this file consults "oclUtils.h" and "shrQATest.h", so I added these two files path in makefile.

But when I try to compile it it still says "undefined reference to 'shrLog' 'shrLogEx' 'oclErrorString'" ... (too many).

I must do it until tomorrow but from last friday I'm still bound it.

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04, I already installed SDK 4.2 and device driver.

Let me know what I must include (header file or library) in makefile.

Answer (score -3):

---

### II.B.   Linux Installation Instructions

1. The OpenCL SDK samples in the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK require a GPU with CUDA Compute 
    Architecture to run properly. For a complete list of CUDA-Architecture compute-enabled GPUs, 
    see the list online at:  http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_learn_products.html
2. The OpenCL applications in the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK require version 258.19 of the NVIDIA 
   Display Driver or later to run on 32 bit or 64 bit Linux.  This required driver is made available to 
   registered developers at: https://nvdeveloper.nvidia.com/login.asp?action=login

   Please make sure to read the Driver Installation Hints Document before you 
   install the driver: http://www.nvidia.com/object/driver_installation_hints.html
3. Uninstall any previous versions of the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK
4. Install the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK by running the installer provided for your OS.

   The default installation folder for the OpenCL SDK is:

   Linux
          $(HOME)/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/

   In the following we will refer to the path that the SDK is installed into as .
5. Build the 32-bit or 64-bit (match the installation OS), release and debug
   configurations, of the entire set of SDK projects and utility dependencies.
   a. Go to /OpenCL
   b. Build:

   - release configuration by typing "make".
   - debug   configuration by typing "make dbg=1".

   Running make at the top level first builds the shared and common utility libraries used by
   the SDK samples (these libraries are simply for convenience and are not part of the OpenCL
   distribution and are not required for your own OpenCL programs). Make then builds each
   of the projects in the SDK.
6. Run the examples from the release or debug directory located in 
   /OpenCL/bin/linux/[release|debug].

   - Most of the SDK applications output messages to a console window that are of interest from the 
     standpoint of understanding basic OpenCL program flow, and several of the applications generate
     graphics output in a separate OpenGL window.
   - Many of the SDK applications present some timing information useful for obtaining an 
     overall perspective of program structure and flow and the time required for setup and execution of 
     significant functions.  The SDK example code, however, has generally been simplified for instructional 
     purposes and is not optimized.  Advanced optimization techniques are beyond the scope of this SDK, and 
     any timing information presented by the samples is not intended for such usage as benchmarking.
   - All of the applications additionally log all the console information to a session log file in the
     same directory as the executables.  Those files are named clearly after the name of the sample app, 
     but with a .txt extension.
   - For convenience, the Makefile in /OpenCL can be used to execute all 
     SDK samples sequentially by typing "make runall" or "make dbg=1 runall".

Comment: sample files should work fine when you follow the above instructions while setting up everything!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542808/what-is-needed-to-compile-opencl-on-ubuntu-and-by-extension-opencl-period