# Intel OpenCL SDK installation on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sdk, opencl, intel, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install OpenCL SDK on ubuntu-14.04. The problem is that I can not find a Linux version of this SDK. All what I found is a Windows version https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk.

Comment: NVIDIA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542808/what-is-needed-to-compile-opencl-on-ubuntu-and-by-extension-opencl-period

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the latest OpenCL runtime for Ubuntu from:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers

Note that it contains only RPM packages, so you'll have to convert them to DEB via alien.

Comment: Now, with the release 15.1 there is Ubuntu support with the so-called "Intel OpenCL™ Code Builder for Ubuntu" package.

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and release 15.1 of the OpenCL SDK:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/rajb245/epGzn

Intel does support RHEL/SLES Linux distros, so the idea of the script is to convert the RPM to a DEB. "alien" didn't work for me, so the script instead downloads and unpacks the RPM structure, moves things around into a DEB structure, repacks it as a DEB file, installs the DEB, and cleans up the broken packages issue that arises from doing the install.

Now that OpenCL Runtime 16.1 is officially available however, this is all kind of moot. Intel now officially supports Ubuntu and the download is [here](http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/9019/opencl_runtime_16.1_x64_ubuntu_5.2.0.10002.tgz).