# NVIDIA OpenCL on Trusty or Mint 17

Tags: opencl, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia, linux-mint

I am having a really hard time getting OpenCL working in Trusty or Mint 17. Im using ppa:xorg-edgers, tried updates and even nvidia-340.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-331-uvm nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-dev opencl-headers nvidia-opencl-dev clinfo
```

Rebooting and then

```
babak@ASUS-G750JH:~$ clinfo
clinfo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)
I: ICD loader reports no usable platforms
```

I have tried this on two Intel based systems with Nvidia GPU's a desktop with a GeForce 280, and a laptop with GeForce 780M with a physically disabled Optimus by the Asus, it only has the Nvidia GPU. A G750JH.

Has anyone done this successfully? Can I roll back and remove the PPA and use the default repo's, would that even make a difference?

Comment: I managed with Ubuntu 15.10 + NVIDIA: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33483311/895245

Answer (score 2):

For the xorg-edgers nvidia-346 packages, I get it working by installing also the `nvidia-opencl-icd-346` package and its dependency `ocl-icd-libopencl1`.

Comment: This saved my bacon on 16.04 as well after installing the cuda toolkit and trying everything to get my Titan X to show up in `clinfo`. Just change `346` for `367` or whatever the latest nvidia driver you have installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what the issue was, but seems that the  ppa:xorg-edgers, may have an issue. Whatever is broken the process below fixes the issue and results in both Cuda and OpenCL working with Nvidia and Ubuntu 14.04 x64

```
sudo apt-get install dkms linux-headers-generic fakeroot build-essential
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run
```

Downloaded from Nvidia, 340.xx supports legacy cards
Yes for all options

```
sudo reboot chmod +x cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb 
dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
chmod +x cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run  sudo ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run
```

Choose option to leave out the GPU Driver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

add to bottom of bashrc

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-6.5 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64 
export GLPATH=/usr/lib/
PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
export PATH

sudo reboot

./ocore_601_OpenCL_v20 --devices
```

Downloaded from http://stanford.edu/~yutongz/ocores/

Outputs:

```
OpenCL compatible devices: 
name: GeForce GTX 780M | platformId: 0 deviceId: 0

cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
make
./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 780M"
......
Truncated
```